# Selecting one record when grouping based min

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       invoice.CustomerRef_FullName AS [Name Invoice],
       receivepayment.CustomerRef_FullName AS [Name RP],
       invoice.RefNumber AS Invoice#,
       receivepayment.RefNumber AS Expr1,
       invoice.AppliedAmount,
       invoice.BalanceRemaining,
       MIN(receivepayment.TotalAmount),
       invoice.TimeCreated
FROM receivepayment
     INNER JOIN invoice ON receivepayment.CustomerRef_FullName = invoice.CustomerRef_FullName
GROUP BY receivepayment.RefNumber;
```

trying to make this query wor. receivepayment.TotalAmount is a decimal. Two tables connected with CustomerRef_FullName and its is varchar.

It gives me an error

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'invoice.CustomerRef_FullName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. You have 7 columns that aren't aggregated in your `SELECT`, but only 1 column in your `GROUP BY` clause. Also, on a different note, `DISTINCT` is pointless with a `GROUP BY`, as an aggregated query will only return 1 row per distinct group.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need distinct with group by

You need  all the columns not involved  in aggreagation function mentioned in group  by

```
    SELECT 
       invoice.CustomerRef_FullName AS [Name Invoice],
       receivepayment.CustomerRef_FullName AS [Name RP],
       invoice.RefNumber AS Invoice#,
       receivepayment.RefNumber AS Expr1,
       invoice.AppliedAmount,
       invoice.BalanceRemaining,
       MIN(receivepayment.TotalAmount),
       invoice.TimeCreated
FROM receivepayment
INNER JOIN invoice ON receivepayment.CustomerRef_FullName = invoice.CustomerRef_FullName
GROUP BY invoice.CustomerRef_FullNam ,
       receivepayment.CustomerRef_FullName ,
       invoice.RefNumber ,
       receivepayment.RefNumber,
       invoice.AppliedAmount,
       invoice.BalanceRemaining,
        invoice.TimeCreated
```

or  for get all the columns you need  a subquery or join  the min value with the correspondi row

```
SELECT 
       invoice.CustomerRef_FullName AS [Name Invoice],
       receivepayment.CustomerRef_FullName AS [Name RP],
       invoice.RefNumber AS Invoice#,
       invoice.AppliedAmount,
       invoice.BalanceRemaining,
       invoice.TimeCreated
FROM receivepayment
INNER JOIN invoice ON receivepayment.CustomerRef_FullName = invoice.CustomerRef_FullName
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT 
         receivepayment.RefNumber AS Expr1,
         MIN(receivepayment.TotalAmount) min_tot,
         invoice.TimeCreated
  FROM receivepayment
       INNER JOIN invoice ON receivepayment.CustomerRef_FullName = invoice.CustomerRef_FullName
  GROUP BY receivepayment.RefNumber;
) t on t.min_tod = receivepayment.TotalAmount 
      AND  receivepayment.RefNumber = t.Expr1
```

Answer (score 0):

Every column in your SELECT clause must either be: (a) an Aggregate Function call like `MIN`, or (b) Listed in the GROUP BY clause.

Think about what you have asked... you are saying "Show me the transactions, grouped by the RefNumber"  But one of the columns that you selected is `invoice.CustomerRef_FullName`.  What if there is more than one `invoice.CustomerRef_FullName` per RefNumber?  For example, a customer could have changed its name at some point and would have 2 names among its invoices.

The 'normal' fix here would be to take all of the columns except for the MIN function call and list them in the GROUP BY Clause.  A somewhat weirder solution is to convert all the fields in the SELECT clause to aggregate function calls like FIRST.

Answer (score 0):

You might find `APPLY` helpful here.  If you want the information about the smallest payment for each invoice:

```
SELECT i.CustomerRef_FullName AS [Name Invoice],
       rp.CustomerRef_FullName AS [Name RP],
       i.RefNumber AS Invoice#,
       rp.RefNumber AS Expr1,
       i.AppliedAmount,
       i.BalanceRemaining,
       rp.TotalAmount,
       i.TimeCreated
FROM invoice i APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) rp.*
      FROM receivepayment rp
      WHERE rp.CustomerRef_FullName = i.CustomerRef_FullName
      ORDER BY rp.TotalAmount ASC
     ) rp;
```